# Убрать действие из ожидания

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qtimer

Есть код, в котором создано окно, в котором находятся кнопки.

Код выполняет следующие действия:

- При нажатии на верхнюю кнопку (настройки), блокируется интерфейс, воспроизводится звук, разблокируется интерфейс.
- При нажатии на левую кнопку (Помощь) просто воспроизводится звук.

[image: Скриншот интерфейса]

Проблема заключается в том, что нажатия на кнопки будто запоминаются в буфер и происходит так, что при нажатии на **`Настройки`** кнопки блокируются и звук воспроизводится, а если при заблокированных кнопках нажать на **`Помощь`**, то после того, как звук закончит воспроизведение и интерфейс разблокируется звук с кнопки **`Помощь`** сразу же воспроизводится, что крайне не нужно.

Кнопки должны принимать действие только в том случае, когда интерфейс разблокирован.

Прилагаю код без собственной редакции

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

 from playsound import playsound



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
    MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
    MainWindow.resize(800, 490)                               # 1200, 490
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet("""
        #MainWindow {                                        /* <--- +++ */
            background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, 
                x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, 
                stop:0 rgba(255, 78, 238, 255), 
                stop:0.318182 rgba(255, 46, 147, 255), 
                stop:0.727273 rgba(106, 198, 255, 255), 
                stop:1 rgba(83, 253, 255, 255));
        }
        """)
    MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
    spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
    self.btn_bool = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

#        self.btn_bool.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
    self.btn_bool.setText("btn_bool")         # + "btn_bool" для тестирования

    self.btn_bool.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
    self.btn_bool.setObjectName("btn_bool")
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_bool)
    self.btn_setting = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_setting.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
    self.btn_setting.setText("")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()

#        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../free-icon-setting-8311467.png"), 
QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("boy33.png"), 
        QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    
    self.btn_setting.setIcon(icon)
    self.btn_setting.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
    self.btn_setting.setObjectName("btn_setting")
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_setting)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
    self.btn_help = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_help.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
    self.btn_help.setText("")
    icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
    
#        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_pomoshh.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, 
QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"), 
        QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    
    self.btn_help.setIcon(icon1)
    self.btn_help.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
    self.btn_help.setObjectName("btn_help")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_help)
    self.btn_water = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_water.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
    self.btn_water.setText("")
    icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
#        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_voda.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, 
QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), 
        QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    
    self.btn_water.setIcon(icon2)
    self.btn_water.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
    self.btn_water.setObjectName("btn_water")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_water)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Дозатор"))
    

#        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # скрыть рамку
#        MainWindow.showFullScreen()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.add_funcs()

def lock_btn(self):
    print(f'def lock_btn(self): 111') 
    self.btn_setting.setEnabled(False)
    self.btn_help.setEnabled(False)
    self.btn_water.setEnabled(False)
    print(f'def lock_btn(self): 222') 

def unlock_btn(self):
    print(f'def unlock_btn(self): ') 
    self.btn_setting.setEnabled(True)
    self.btn_help.setEnabled(True)
    self.btn_water.setEnabled(True)

def play_set(self):
    print(f'def play_set(self): 111') 
    playsound('sounds/shot.wav')                           # set.mp3 
    playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
    playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
    playsound('sounds/login.mp3') 
    playsound('sounds/logout.mp3')
    playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
    playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
    print(f'def play_set(self): 222') 
    
    self.unlock_btn()                                      # +++

def add_funcs(self):
    print(f'def add_funcs(self): \n') 
    self.btn_setting.clicked.connect(self.settings)
    self.btn_help.clicked.connect(self.help)

def settings(self):
    print(f'\ndef settings(self): ') 
    self.lock_btn()
    

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(20, self.play_set)           # <---- !!!
    
    #raise SystemExit

def help(self): 
    print(f'def help(self): \n') #
    playsound('sounds/login.mp3')                           # help.mp3
    playsound('sounds/logout.mp3')                          # help1.mp3
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я совсем не знаю как работает библиотека *playsound*.

А возможный вариант решения проблемы,
может выглядеть примерно так:

```
...

    def settings(self):
# !!! Отключает сигнал в объекте-отправителе от метода в объекте-получателе. 
# !!!                            vvvvvvvvvv       
        self.btn_setting.clicked.disconnect(self.settings)          # <---- +++
        self.btn_help.clicked.disconnect(self.help)                 # <---- +++
# !!!                         ^^^^^^^^^^

...

    def play_set(self):
        ... 
        self.unlock_btn() 
        
# !!! Создает соединение заданного типа от сигнала в объекте-отправителе 
# !!! к методу в объекте-получателе. 
# !!! через 1 сек. после выполнения метода unlock_btn()
# !!!                            vvvv - возможно время прийдется изменить
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.add_funcs)           # <---- +++    

...
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from playsound import playsound


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(800, 490)               
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("""
            #MainWindow {                                       
                background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, 
                    x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, 
                    stop:0 rgba(255, 78, 238, 255), 
                    stop:0.318182 rgba(255, 46, 147, 255), 
                    stop:0.727273 rgba(106, 198, 255, 255), 
                    stop:1 rgba(83, 253, 255, 255));
            }
            """)
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.btn_bool = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

#        self.btn_bool.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_bool.setText("btn_bool")         # + "btn_bool" для тестирования

        self.btn_bool.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.btn_bool.setObjectName("btn_bool")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_bool)
        self.btn_setting = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_setting.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_setting.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()

#        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../free-icon-setting-8311467.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("boy33.png"), 
            QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btn_setting.setIcon(icon)
        self.btn_setting.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.btn_setting.setObjectName("btn_setting")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_setting)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.btn_help = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_help.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_help.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        
#        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_pomoshh.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"), 
            QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btn_help.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_help.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.btn_help.setObjectName("btn_help")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_help)
        self.btn_water = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_water.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_water.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
#        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_voda.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), 
            QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btn_water.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btn_water.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.btn_water.setObjectName("btn_water")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_water)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Дозатор"))
# !!! Закомментировал для понимания проблемы
#        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # скрыть рамку
#        MainWindow.showFullScreen()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.add_funcs()

    def lock_btn(self):
        print(f'def lock_btn(self): 111') 
        self.btn_setting.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_help.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_water.setEnabled(False)
        print(f'def lock_btn(self): 222') 

    def unlock_btn(self):
        print(f'def unlock_btn(self): ') 
        self.btn_setting.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_help.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_water.setEnabled(True)

    def play_set(self):
        print(f'def play_set(self): 111') 
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')                           # set.mp3 
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        playsound('sounds/login.mp3') 
        playsound('sounds/logout.mp3')
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        print(f'def play_set(self): 222') 
        
        self.unlock_btn() 
        
# !!! Создает соединение заданного типа от сигнала в объекте-отправителе 
# !!! к методу в объекте-получателе. 
# !!! через 1 сек. после выполнения метода unlock_btn()
# !!!                            vvvv - возможно время прийдется изменить
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.add_funcs)           # <---- +++

    def add_funcs(self):
        print(f'def add_funcs(self): \n') 
        self.btn_setting.clicked.connect(self.settings)
        self.btn_help.clicked.connect(self.help)

    def settings(self):
        print(f'\ndef settings(self): ') 

# !!! Отключает сигнал в объекте-отправителе от метода в объекте-получателе. 
# !!!                            vvvvvvvvvv       
        self.btn_setting.clicked.disconnect(self.settings)          # <---- +++
        self.btn_help.clicked.disconnect(self.help)                 # <---- +++
        
        self.lock_btn()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(20, self.play_set) 
        
        #raise SystemExit

    def help(self): 
        print(f'def help(self): \n') #
        playsound('sounds/login.mp3')                           # help.mp3
        playsound('sounds/logout.mp3')                          # help1.mp3
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В целом, это прям то что нужно, огромное спасибо

Comment: @СергейКачалов пожалуйста?